# Stop componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-lifecycle

I am working on a react app where I want to stop my component from unmounting based on some conditions.

As far as I have researched I found one option of setRouteLeaveHook using react router (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509898/cancel-componentwillunmount-if-a-form-is-incomplete)).
But the problem is I have same route i.e url is same for both components. Also I don't have this.props.router option or this.context.router option where I can pass this.

Is there something I can do ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page/45869459#45869459

Comment: Actually the component i want to stop from unmounting is a child component whose route remains same all time. So how will it work when i am not changing any route ?

Comment: why is the child component unmounting then? are you having a conditional rendering for it

Comment: yes it's conditional rendering.

Comment: Then you shouldn't render the component conditionally rather render the content of the component conditionally to avoid unmounting if the condition is false