# REACT: How to cancel componentWillUnmount() method if data is not saved

Tags: reactjs

I want to cancel componentWillUnmount()  method if data is not saved.I have state property IsSaved which defines whether data is saved or not?
I want to write something like 
    componentWillUnmount()
    {
       if(!IsSaved)
       {
         //Cancel unmount stay on same component
       }
    }
Is this possible? Or I need to achieve it by some other way?

Comment: Hey KRN! Welcome to SO. Check out this post, I think its a similar one to the one you're asking here (So long as you're using react-router?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509898/cancel-componentwillunmount-if-a-form-is-incomplete

Comment: You can't you will need to remount the component if you need to on failure (from the parent)

Comment: hello, could you please elaborate more? what is the actual condition in which isSaved == false?

Comment: IsSaved is false intially when my component opens in edit mode. On Save button click Im setting IsSaved to true. In case any change happens again I set it as false. Now there are many navigation links in top bar and side bar, if user clicks on those links I want to show popup to confirm that user wants redirect and his changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You cant cancel "componentWillMount" as it is a lifecycle callback.
What you CAN do is to avoid component unmounting.
So if you can prevent to propagate an action that will cause the unmount of a component, this is the right approach to your problem in react.

**NOTE:**

If the component unmount is triggered by react-router you can try *setRouteLeaveHook*

```js
componentWillMount() {
    this.unregisterLeaveHook = props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(props.route, this.routerWillLeave.bind(this));
}

routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
  return false;        
}
```

And when you want to unmount component unregister the hook:

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unregisterLeaveHook();
}
```

ref: [How can I prevent the unmount in React Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828224/how-can-i-prevent-the-unmount-in-react-components)